# Как определить, где пишет пользователь в лс или в группе телеграмм?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram

Возникла потребность узнать, где именно юзер обращается к боту: в лс или же в группе боту. Хочется реализовать способ, при котором в лс будут отправляться одни сообщения, а в группу другие.

Пишу на python/aiogram

Answer (score 1):

Уже нашел способ решения своей проблемы. Для этого стоит обратить внимание на `chat.type`

https://tlgrm.ru/docs/bots/api#chat